# random orderBy in ng-repeat returns [$rootScope:infdig] error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a large array of objects which I am printing with `ng-repea`t which keeps on shuffling infinitely in dom, any quick solution will be appreciated.

Below is the HMTL:

```
ng-repeat="_video in return_array_for_ngrepeat() | orderBy: random"
```

My `$rootScope` function:

```
 $rootScope.return_array_for_ngrepeat = function () {
    return _.values(data[102]);
}

$rootScope.random = function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why does this error happened?

You make a lot of calls to `random()`, and Angular will keep on evaluating the expressions, until it reachs the limit of 10 digest iterations. That is the cause of your error.

---

### How to solve it?

You have to set your random order **outside the template**, for example in your controller.

```
angular.forEach($rootScope.list, function(item) {
    $rootScope.randomizedList.push({
        item: item,
        rank: 0.5 - $window.Math.random()
    });
});
```

You can now loop over the `randomizedList` array.

```
<p ng-repeat="i in randomizedList | orderBy:'rank'">{{i.item}</p>
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/x1c7aLLd/2/)